# Why do the front wheels of my car get so hot?

Tags: brakes

As soon as I've driven any distance, say 30 km at about 60 km/hr, when I stop the car I can feel heat from both of my front wheels. I compared the heat from my wheels to other vehicles and I can say it's significantly more than, like 20 times, the heat from other vehicles.

I would like to know if there is something else i should check?

I did the following:

1. replaced the brake-disk
2. replaced the brake pads
3. serviced the brake pad hub
4. replaced the bearings

I checked if the installation was properly done and confirmed everything looks okay.

I do not know what to do to stop the wheels from heating up, please help inform me what to do?

Comment: Jack up the front of your car, put in neutral and spin the wheels.
Do they spin free or do they turn hard?

Comment: Your brakes are sticking. This is not good. I wouldn't drive on it like that as the brakes can get hot enough to lose effectiveness and cause a crash.

Comment: Did you do the work yourself, or was it done by a mechanic? It should go back to the mechanic for sure if you didn't do it.

Comment: a mechanic did the work and i checked to see if everything was properly installed.

Comment: i jacked the wheel up and noticed the brake pads are too thick they keep in contact with the brake disc even when the brakes are released, i took out the disc brakes and grind of some of the surface and it helped the wheel is no longer heating up

Comment: Check master break cylender It is faulty and stucking

Answer (score 5):

Calipers are designed to float. If the disc calipers slides were not proper lubricated and free to move, as well as the piston being retracted, it could cause the pads to be pressing the rotor all the time and create lots of heat.

The other thing is if the bearings were installed with too much torque could cause binding and require more force to roll. This would increase friction considerably.

Answer (score 2):

You changed almost everything: *you also need to check the calipers and service/change them if the pistons doesn't retract as expected*, after pressing and releasing the pedal. Hot brakes means the pads/shoes are not being correctly released and they are still in contact with the disk/drum.

While you drive that way, pay special attention to water/ice in the road: if the disk are getting hot and they continuously get wet because water puddles in the road, they will bend.

In any case, never, never cool the hot brake with water.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the bearings are too tight. I had this issue with a VW on the rear wheels. They overheated to the point of self destructing. The bearings were ground to powder and the race was shredded and the spindle looked like it had gone through a lathe. Incredible but true, the wheels themselves got rammed into the wheel wells and were held on the edge of the spindle.

Bearings should enough play that they float inside the race and yet keep the wheel attached.